# Python CSV writerow to specific column in already opened file

Tags: python, csv

I am struggling with `csv` module and `writerow` method.

NOTE: This is simplified the code as much as I could. I am asking for understanding.
I provided [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as much as I could.

WHAT I'VE GOT:

Three tables in the database:

> MODEL_test - contain data on which algorithm will learn
>
> my_prediction - contain unseen data on which algorithm will be applied
>
> OUT_predictions - contain output from algorithm `predict` method

In the first step, I create a new CSV file and keep in open till alliteration for the current algorithm is finished. Before training iteration starts I append CSV file rows with first 7 values from unseen table data, so data won't be multiplied. Then after each algorithm iteration, I want to append already opened file with `OUT_prediction` values.

**CODE:**

```
import csv
import datetime

def export_to_csv():

    ldb = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = ldb.cursor()

    table_name = 'my_predictions'

    training_size = 3

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    file_name = str.format('my_predictions {}', now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"))

    export_columns = ['COLUMN ' + str(n) for n in range(1, 8)] + \
                     ['OUTPUT ' + str(n) for n in range(1, training_size + 1)]

    with open('archived/' + file_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(export_columns)
        output_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=export_columns)

        for o in range(1, 500): # < write all unseen data from database to csv

            c.execute(str.format('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ID=?', table_name), [o])
            fetch_one = c.fetchone()

            writer.writerow(fetch_one[1:7])

        for t in range(training_size): #for each iteration write output to csv

            # some machine learning training code

            prediction = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] # <-- sample output from predictions

            combined_set = list(map(str, prediction))

            ids = 1

            for each in combined_set:
                c.execute(str.format('INSERT INTO OUTPUT_prediction VALUES ({})',
                                     ",".join(["?" for _ in range(1, len([ids] + [int(each)]) + 1)])), [ids] + [int(each)])

                ids += 1

            ldb.commit()

            for o in range(1, 500): # <-- write down output from last prediction iteration to specific column
                c.execute(str.format('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ID=?', table_name), [o])
                fetch_output = c.fetchone()

                output_writer.writeheader()
                output_writer.writerow({'OUTPUT ' + str(t + 1): fetch_output[-1]})  # <-- columns remain empty
```

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM**

When code finish and I open the file I can see that OUTPUT columns remain empty

[CSV IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag7qj.png)

EDIT: I don't want to use `pandas` and `to_csv` because of thy are very slow. Sometimes my unseen data has 1 million lines and it takes half an hour for a single iteration using `to_csv`.

Comment: because we dont have the database.db file, it will be difficult to point out. But one advice will be to break the whole logic into chucks and print/debug.

Comment: database file has over 14GB size :D

Comment: first 20 rows will do. just filter... or recreate with a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I know what I've done wrong and found solution for this situation, but I'm not satisfied with it. When I try to add new column in `w` mode new data is always written at the end of the file. When I set `csv_file.seek(0)` old data is overwritten.

Also I have tried to reopen file in `r+` mode and set `csv_file.seek(0)`, but got same outcome.

I will use `xlwings` for this task, because it gives me more control, but still do not know how it will affect input data speed. My goal is to prepare summary report with unseen data, output for each iteration and statistical information.

SOLUTION (with `r+`):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
file_name = str.format('my_predictions {}', now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"))

export_columns = ['COLUMN ' + str(n) for n in range(1, 8)] + \
                 ['OUTPUT ' + str(n) for n in range(1, training_size + 1)]


with open('archived/' + file_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:

    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(export_columns)

    for o in range(1, 500):

        c.execute(str.format('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ID=?', table_name), [o])
        fetch_one = c.fetchone()

        writer.writerow(fetch_one[1:7])

for t in range(training_size):

    # some machine learning training code

    prediction = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] # <-- sample output from predictions

    combined_set = List(Map(Str, prediction))

    # ids = 1
    #
    # for each in combined_set:
    #    c.execute(str.format('INSERT INTO OUTPUT_prediction VALUES ({})',
    #                         ",".join(["?" for _ in range(1, len([ids] + [int(each)]) + 1)])), [ids] + [int(each)])
    #
    #    ids += 1
    #
    # ldb.commit()

    with open('archived/' + file_name + '.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csv_file:

        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_input = csv.reader(csv_file)
        rows = List(csv_input)
        writer.writerow(export_columns)

        for row, o in zip(rows, combined_set):

            row += [o]

            writer.writerow(row)
```